# Strange product of groups

Tags: group-theory, invariant-theory

I am working on S. Mukai "Invariants and Moduli" (http://www.math.ens.fr/~benoist/refs/Mukai.pdf ) and on page 71 he writes in a Theorem:
\begin{align}
"\text{.... then the ring of invariants under the action of } G \cdot T \cong \mathbb{C}^6\cdot (\mathbb{C}^{\times})^8 \subset GL(18, \mathbb{C}) \text{...} ".
\end{align}
I don't know what kind of product is meant here and have not found anything similar to this. So maybe someone has an idea. It seems a bit weird, that the product is a subset of the invertible $18 \times 18$-matrices... $\mathbb{C}^6$ is the additive group and $(\mathbb{C}^{\times})^8$ is the multiplicative group. $G \subset \mathbb{C}^N$ is a subspace of dimension $N-3$ and $T \subset (\mathbb{C}^{\times})^N$ is a subgroup of dimension N-1, if you need know this.

Comment: It seems to me that he has linear actions of the groups $\mathbb{C}^9$ and $\mathbb{C}^{*9}$ on $\mathbb{C}^{18}$, which (as he says) commute. Then $G$ is defined as a certain subgroup of $\mathbb{C}^9$, which he says is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^6$; and $T$ a certain subgroup of $\mathbb{C}^{*9}$ which he says is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^{*8}$. Then surely $G\cdot T$ is just the ordinary product of commuting subgroups of $GL(18,\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: Perhaps if you just write down the matrices for the actions of $\mathbb{C}^N$ and $\mathbb{C}^{*N}$ you'll see why everything is in $GL(2N, \mathbb{C})$.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right. Thank you :)